# What is the execution logic of the expression in C?

Tags: c, expression, execution

Suppose I a couple of expression in C. Different outputs are provided.

```
int i =2,j;
j= i + (2,3,4,5);
printf("%d %d", i,j);
//Output= 2 7

 j= i + 2,3,4,5;
 printf("%d %d", i,j);
 //Output 2 4
```

How does the execution take place in both expression with and without bracket giving different outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Comma` operator works by evaluating all expressions and returning the last expression.

```
j= i + (2,3,4,5);
```

becomes

```
j= i + (5); //j=7
```

In the second expression assignment operator takes precedence over comma operator,so

```
j= i + 2,3,4,5;
```

becomes

```
(j= i + 2),3,4,5; //j=4
```